# Real time Mapping application Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, polling, android-maps-v2

I need two create an Android mapping application which will have two type of clients and a webservice.

**Client Type 1(Client to be tracked)**
The location of this client needs to be tracked and sent to the sever in realtime. There will be atmost 10-15 of these type of clients

**Client Type 2(Client to view all type 1 clients)**
These clients need to display the location of type 1 clients in realtime(less than 10-15 sec latency would be preferable). There can be 100's of type 2 to clients requesting data.

**Webservice**
Will return the latest position of type 1 client's as JSON on every request.This will be written in PHP and mySQL will be used to store client type 1 information.

Clients Type 1 and Type 2 are Android Clients.

What is the best(Most efficient and elegent method) of achieving this other than bolling periodically on client type 2 and posting data periodically on client type 1.

Comment: long polling or websocket could prevent the need for the polling from client 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just let Client Type 2 poll the webservice every xx amount of seconds, depending on how often you want it refreshed.

You could use push notifications but as there are lots of client type 2, you'd be sending a lot of notifications.

Furthermore, the goal of things such as push notifications, is to keep non-active apps up to date, when updates are at an unpredictable and relatively rare rate. Per example with news apps, that only use notifications for really big news. It can take days before 'big news' happens, and you do not want the app constantly polling for this while non-active.

Your app however, sounds as it will only do work while active anyway, and will have to update around a fixed pace.

Using push notifications or sockets will not result in less battery usage or other factors than simply using polling at a fixed rate, assuming the above about your app.

Comment: Yes your assumptions about the app are correct. Yes Push is really out of the question.

Comment: So use simple polling for client 2, no need to complicate things ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Client Type 1**
Take a look at the [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) class which will fire events when the clients location changes.

**Webservice**
Store a timestamp on each location updated event and provide two service endpoints. One can provide the locations of all Type 1 clients. The other can provide all the locations of Type 1 clients since Timestamp X.

**Client Type 2**
On startup pull back the location of all Type 1 clients and store a timestamp for time now(). Poll your service every X seconds for records that have changed since previous timestamp. Store updated timestamp.

This method is slightly harder work on your server as each of your Type 2 clients will be requesting different information so caching is hard, but as the server is only storing the data for 10-15 type 1 clients that should no problem. It will reduce network traffic as no data is sent for Type 1 clients that have not moved.

There is limited advantage to investigating Long Polling/web sockets (higher battery consumption) and Push Notifications seem a bit high maintenance for something that sounds like a foreground application.

Comment: Yes I planned on something similar. Was just curious to know if there are any other/better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this question:

You can also use Java WebSocket for bi-directional communication between the android application and the server. Once client2's location is updated, you can push that to the server and then use websocket connection to update it on the client1 applications.

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

For iOS: https://github.com/square/SocketRocket